How to fix the Google warning "Unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager"
I am getting warnings from Google play once published the application
Warning:

We found that your app contains security vulnerabilities, which can
expose user information or damage a user’s device. This is a violation
of Device and Network Abuse policy. Specifically, your app(s) contain
an unsafe implementation of TrustManager.
Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not
resolve this issue by January 28, 2025.

Below is the implementation of X509TrustManager in my code.
final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        return new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        checkValidity(X509InterfaceType.X_509_INTERFACE_TYPE_CLIENT_TRUSTED,
                                originalTrustManager, certs, authType);
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        checkValidity(X509InterfaceType.X_509_INTERFACE_TYPE_SERVER_TRUSTED,
                                originalTrustManager, certs, authType);
                    }
                }
        };
    }

Below method invocations from checkClientTrusted and checkServerTrusted
 private void checkValidity(X509InterfaceType interfaceType, X509TrustManager originalTrustManager, X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        if (certs == null || certs.length == 0) {
            OBCFileLogger.getInstance()
                    .writeToErrorFile(NetworkRequestUtils.TAG +
                            interfaceType.name() +
                            " ,Certificate list is null or empty");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Certificate is null or empty");
        }
        if (authType == null || authType.length() == 0) {
            OBCFileLogger.getInstance()
                    .writeToErrorFile(NetworkRequestUtils.TAG +
                            interfaceType.name() +
                            " ,Authtype is null or empty");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Certificate is null or empty");
        }

        if (!authType.equalsIgnoreCase("ECDHE_RSA") &&
                !authType.equalsIgnoreCase("ECDHE_ECDSA") &&
                !authType.equalsIgnoreCase("RSA") &&
                !authType.equalsIgnoreCase("ECDSA")) {
            OBCFileLogger.getInstance()
                    .writeToErrorFile(NetworkRequestUtils.TAG +
                            interfaceType.name() + " ,Certificate is not trusted, authType is not valid");
            throw new CertificateException("Certificate is not trusted");
        }

        try {
            if (certs.length > 0) {
                certs[0].checkValidity();
            } else {
                if (interfaceType == X509InterfaceType.X_509_INTERFACE_TYPE_CLIENT_TRUSTED) {
                    originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                } else {
                    originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            OBCFileLogger.getInstance()
                    .writeToErrorFile(NetworkRequestUtils.TAG +
                            " " +
                            interfaceType.name() + "Other exception: Issue in checking validity: " + e.toString());
            throw new CertificateException("Certificate is not valid or trusted");
        }
    }

